# How to tell RStudio to use R version from Anaconda

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I have installed anaconda and the conda package R on my mac os x yosemite.
When I type

```
which R
```

in my terminal, I get the following output

```
/Users/giovannisoldi/anaconda/bin/R
```

so it is actually linking to the right version. However, when I open RStudio, I can see that the old version of R located in

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/
```

is still used. I tried to link to the current version of R in Anaconda, with the following command:

```
ln -sfhv /Users/giovannisoldi/anaconda/bin/ /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current
```

However, by doing this RStudio complains that it can't locate R.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: In RStudio, from the menu: Tools -> Global options... Then set the R version

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R

Comment: This doesn't work because RStudio will not start if it cannot find your version of R.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I did it:

```
which R
/Users/admin/anaconda/bin/R
```

In my `~/.bashrc` (or your `~/.bash_profile`) I put this:

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/Users/admin/anaconda/bin/R
```

Then `source ~/.bashrc`

(you now have to open RStudio from the terminal) finally, you can type

```
rstudio
```

or you can, again, edit your `~/.bashrc` with `alias rstudio='open -a RStudio .'` and now the `rstudio` command will open RStudio in your current dir.

Comment: no O__o . This method you made makes perfect sense.  I don't know how to get it to work tho. I've tried to describe my situation in as much detail as possible here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534383/how-to-set-up-conda-installed-r-for-use-with-rstudio

Comment: @O.rka, ohh okay. I'll spend some time on that since I've had issues like that on other computers / OSes, so it'd be good for me too

Comment: I'll be on my computer a bit today so let me know if there's any commands you want me to run to get some more specs. Thanks a lot @sndean

Comment: On elementary OS, I put `export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/home/user/miniconda3/envs/R/lib/R/bin/R` into `~/.profile` and it works.