# How to set up conda-installed R for use with RStudio?

Tags: r, environment-variables, rstudio, anaconda, conda

[image]

I've been trying to set up my `R` using `conda` (eventually to use with Beaker Notebook) and I want to be able to use `RStudio` with my conda-installed version of `R`.

My method of installing `R`:

```
conda install -c r r
conda install -c r r-essentials
conda install -c r r-rserve
conda install -c r r-devtools
conda install -c r r-rcurl
conda install -c r r-RJSONIO
conda install -c r r-jpeg
conda install -c r r-png
conda install -c r r-roxygen2
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda bioconductor-edger
```

I ran that version of R (I only installed this version)

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin11.0.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin11.0.0                
system         x86_64, darwin11.0.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.1                         
year           2016                        
month          06                          
day            21                          
svn rev        70800                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
nickname       Bug in Your Hair
```

Running `R` in `Jupyter` is kind of buggy.  For example, when it outputs errors, it outputs to `stdout` and splits every character in the string with a linebreak.  I want to use `RStudio` but I don't want to install another version of `R`.

**How can I route my conda version of `R` into RStudio?**

Here's my `.bash_profile` not sure if this will be useful:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
# added by Anaconda3 4.0.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/bin/R
```

I've been trying to follow these tutorials but I am lost.  I'm really not too familiar with environment variables and such things.

(1) https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207830688-Using-RStudio-with-conda

(2) [Launch mac eclipse with environment variables set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829749/launch-mac-eclipse-with-environment-variables-set)

when I looked for my `R` it directed me to:

```
$ which R
/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/bin/R
```

but the directions from (1) is using this path which is very confusing:

```
/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/lib/R/bin/R
```

I tried doing what this guy did and added this to my `.bash_profile` but it didn't work.  I even made a `.bashrc` but it still didn't work (I `sourced` both after I added the lines)

`export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/bin/R`

[How to tell RStudio to use R version from Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764830/how-to-tell-rstudio-to-use-r-version-from-anaconda)

Unfortunately, `anaconda` has no tutorial for this in https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration

Comment: `conda activate your-r-env` and then `rstudio`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So long as `which R` shows up a working R interpreter (which it should do if you have installed the `r` package from `conda` and activated your environment) then launching `rstudio` *from that same environment* should pick it up just fine.

For a test, on `ArchLinux`, I built and installed: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rstudio-desktop-git/

.. then force removed the R interpreter (`pacman -Rdd r`), then installed `r` from `conda` (`conda install -c r r`) and it worked fine. I then closed my terminal and opened a new one (so that the correct `conda` environment *was not* activated and successfully launched RStudio with the following command: `RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/home/ray/r_3_3_1-x64-3.5/bin/R rstudio`

I think the crux is to launch `RStudio` from the right environment? Your `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` are only sourced when you run `bash`. For environment variables to be set so that the your desktop environment knows about them, on Linux, you should put them in `~/.profile` or else in `/etc/pam.d` (you may need to logout or shutdown after making those changes) and on OS X, you should check out https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57385

Comment: How can I make sure `rstudio` is launching from that same environemnt?

Comment: Can't I use the conda R interpreter with a default RStudio installation (downloaded from RStudio website)?

Answer (score 18):

See https://anaconda.org/r/rstudio:

```
$ conda install -c r rstudio
```

Then from command line:

```
$ rstudio
```

(It is how I installed it and it works.)

Comment: In hindsight, I should have done that.  I don't think this was an option for when I first tried it.  At least we have at least 3 different ways to get this to work for people :)

Comment: On Windows 10 and Anaconda3 it's simply `conda install rstudio`

Comment: `$ rstudio &`, run as a deamon process

Comment: BUT: rstudio in conda is not updated. It seems to be rather outdated i.e. 1.1 on osx vs. now 1.4 available.

Comment: **Outdated answer.** As mentioned by others, RStudio from Conda is not maintained and will only work with at most R 3.6.

Comment: It is now possible to install rstudio via the conda forge, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76174701/2166823.

Comment: If using conda rstudio should be installed using conda-forge as stated in this answer  https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/76174701/2166823

Answer (score 11):

## Update: ADD THIS TO `~/.bash_profile` !

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R="/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/bin/R"
launchctl setenv RSTUDIO_WHICH_R $RSTUDIO_WHICH_R
```

Credits to @Z-Shiyi for the last line https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3316#issuecomment-241246755

---

An addition to what @Ray Donnelly said above.  Basically, it has to be executed from the correct environment (i.e. run it from the terminal).

**You can either:**

(A) Put this in your `~/.bash_profile`
`export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/Users/[yourusername]/anaconda/bin/R` (if youre using conda but you could put any `R` path)

(B) then type this in the terminal after it's been sourced (either restart terminal or do `source .bash_profile`): `open -a RStudio`
That should work.

**or you can do what I did:**

(A) open up automator (sorry if you're not on a mac; this will only work on mac)

(B) use a `Run Shell Script`

(C) then delete `cat` that's already in there and put in:

`export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/Users/[yourusername]/anaconda/bin/R
open -a RStudio`

(D) Save it as something like `run_rstudio.app` then just run that and it should work:
[image]

Comment: Since the latest 4.3 release of Anaconda Distribution, none of this should be necessary. Installing and launching RStudio from Anaconda Navigator should 'just work' and, from Terminal, provided you activate your env properly (https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html) `open $CONDA_PREFIX/Applications/RStudio.app` should also work.

Comment: down-voting for the headline, which is (1) outdated for anyone running macOS 11+ (a lot of ppl) and (2) kind of obnoxious

Answer (score 8):

## Launch RStudio from Activated Conda Environment

At least for Mac OS X, I find that it is sufficient to activate the environment in a shell session, then launch RStudio.

```
$ conda activate my_r_env
$ /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/RStudio
```

Once in R, one can verify that values of `R.home()` and `.libPaths()` point to the environment-specific locations.

The advantage here is that you aren't fixed to whatever was last set in the environment variables, e.g., via `.bash_profile`. Instead, one can have many R-based environments and switch between them (or run multiple ones simultaneously) without tampering with global settings.

#### Suggested Aliases for Convenience

Perhaps the only global setting I might recommend is to add an alias for `rstudio` to your `.bash_profile` so you don't have to type the full path every time, like

```
alias rstudio='/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/RStudio &'
```

which enables one to then do

```
$ conda activate my_r_env
$ rstudio
$
```

where the `&` enables one to continue using the shell, or close it, without affecting the RStudio instance.

#### Auto-detecting architecture

The newer RStudio builds for macOS ship in a unified format, including both x86_64 and aarch64 binaries. Many Conda R packages are not yet built for **osx-arm64** architecture (for example, all of Bioconda), requiring users to create environments that emulate **osx-64** and launching `rstudio` as above will be incompatible with this. Here's what I use on Apple Silicon machines to automatically switch the RStudio architecture.

**~/.zshrc**

```bash
alias crun='conda run --no-capture-output --live-stream -n'

crunr() {
  ## is arm64?
  conda run -n $1 R --version | grep 'aarch64' > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    crun $1 /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/RStudio &
  else
    crun $1 arch -x86_64 /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/RStudio &
  fi
}
```

That is, I have two commands `crun` and `crunr`, which each take an environment name as an argument. So, I can do stuff like:

```
## launch RStudio with **osx-arm64** environment
crunr r43

## launch RStudio with **osx-64** environment
crunr r43_x86
```

Comment: If you wish to have only one version of Rstudio (with your settings), but interact with different conda environments, this is the perfect solution (cannot attest to whether that works with other operating systems).

Comment: Works great with macOS.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a version of RStudio in the [conda forge repo](https://github.com/conda-forge/rstudio-feedstock), which can be used to install the more recent versions of RStudio (such as `2022.12.0`).

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge rstudio-desktop
```

Note that when you are creating your R conda environment, it is important that you [only use packages from the same channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733465/2166823) and don't mix e.g. conda-forge with the default channel (this can lead to errors such as `unable to load shared object '/home/joel/miniconda3/envs/r/lib/R/library/ragg/libs/ragg.so'` (also happens with `stringi` often)). One way to insure that channel mixing does not happen is to specify the channel with `-c` and also use `--override-channels` to prevent that the default channels are searched at all:

```bash
conda create -n r --override-channels -c conda-forge r-base r-devtools rstudio-desktop
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by showing a YAML that others could reuse. YAMLs can include a `nodefaults` under the channel section to exclude any channels not defined in the YAML.

Comment: @joelostblom This didn't work for me. Wondering if it still works for you. I get PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - rstudio-desktop `conda create -n QAQC --override-channels -c conda-forge r-base r-devtools rstudio-desktop`

Comment: @ENIAC-6 Yes, it still works for me. I'm on Linux, so maybe the conda packages don't exist for your platform? In general, I'm trying to move from RStudio to VS Code for my R editing needs as I much prefer that editor experience so that might be another option to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Update: The Anaconda Distribution now has packages for RStudio so you should be able to use that and not have to jump through any hoops at all. You can also install it directly the Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: I recently saw this when I opened up `anaconda navigator` for the first time.   I added my solution above.  It has been working perfectly so far.

Comment: **Update:** Anaconda abandoned maintaining RStudio builds for Conda, and while [Conda Forge is discussing picking it up](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/issues/13424), there's no momentum. This might change, however, once RStudio transitions from Qt to Electron (supposed to drop this summer), since it should simplify the build. Anyway, point is Conda does not *reliably* provide RStudio builds.

Comment: Thank you for the link to that issue @merv! It is now possible to install rstudio via the conda forge, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76174701/2166823.

Answer (score 1):

Making a soft link works for me with RStudio v2023.09.1:

```bash
sudo ln -s /opt/miniconda3/envs/r-4.3/bin/R /usr/bin/
sudo ln -s /opt/miniconda3/envs/r-4.3/lib/R/lib/libR.so /usr/lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

if is up to any good (now)... `conda` has the package `rstudioapi` which brings `Rstudio` to your local environment, and picks up the local/default `r-base` installed of your active environment.

you can install it (once your environment is *activated*) by typing:

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-rstudioapi
```

then you just type (inside your environment): **rstudio**

Comment: This did not work for me

Comment: what was the error?
do you installed R-studio outside any conda environment?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Here is what I entered. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2. `mamba create -n mystudio` `mamba activate mystudio` `mamba install -c conda-forge r-rstudioapi` `rstudio`


```
(mystudio) noah@CNPRC:~/projects/dev$ rstudio
rstudio: command not found
```

Comment: you sure you install ```rstudio``` before calling it?

Comment: I see the confusion.  I am aware there is a dated rstudio available in conda. I was under the assumption that rstudioapi could be used to install a newer version of rstudio, one that is more uptodate.