# Install R packages using conda via an environment.yml file

Tags: r, installation, anaconda, conda, miniconda

Normally I create conda environments like...

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
conda activate env_name
```

Normally I work in Python, where a typical `environment.yml` simple file might looks like this...

```
name: env_name
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pip=19.3
  - pandas=0.24.2
  - pip:
    - scipy==1.2.1
```

What should the `environment.yml` file look like to install R packages? The packages are on CRAN

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A general rule of thumb is that most R packages have corresponding packages in Anaconda Cloud with the prefix `r-` added. While the **defaults** channel covers commonly-used packages, the **conda-forge** channel has the most thorough coverage of CRAN and has [helpful scripts for adding new ones](https://github.com/bgruening/conda_r_skeleton_helper). I would generally recommend prioritizing **conda-forge** when creating R environments.

For bioinformaticians, all Bioconductor packages are available through the **bioconda** channel, with a `bioconductor-` prefix and lowercase. For example, `SingleCellExperiment` is packaged as `bioconductor-singlecellexperiment`.

A good place to start is simply searching Anaconda Cloud ([example search](https://anaconda.org/search?q=tidyverse)).

### Example

Let's assume you want the `tidyverse` umbrella package and wish to use R v4.1. A YAML for this would be

```
name: my_r_env
channels:
 - conda-forge
dependencies:
 - r-base=4.1
 - r-tidyverse
```

---

### Additional Notes

Avoid using `install.packages()` from within any R sessions - it is prone to dynamic linking issues due to the R instance's unawareness of compiling inside the environment. This is not an issue for pure R packages, but in that case it should be simple to add the package to **conda-forge** (takes about 15 mins of work and a ~12-24hr turnaround, IME).

Avoid the RStudio packages from Conda - it is an abandoned project and the old versions are incompatible with newer R versions. This may change once [RStudio switches from Qt to Electron](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7389). Still, [there are better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534383/how-to-set-up-conda-installed-r-for-use-with-rstudio/62737170#62737170) to load an environment into RStudio, without having to install the full IDE *inside the environment*.

Comment: ....and when it is _not_ available through those channelse?

Comment: @LudvigH depends on where it is available and whether it requires compiling. If you have specific details, I’d recommend asking a new question. Tag me again here if you’d like me to have a look.

Comment: I wrote it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65984771/how-to-install-cran-packages-in-environment-yml and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: where to specify r version?

Comment: @liang you can add `r-base=4.1` as a dependency (for example)

Comment: @merv is it still true that `install.packages()` is to be avoided? At least it looks like packages get installed into the environment when doing so.

Comment: @Stefan yes, I still recommend avoiding. While pure R packages tend not to have issues, compiled packages often run into linking problems. Moreover, it's just not good practice reproducibility-wise. This is *the* major concern for scientists like myself - though the portability (working across Linux and macOS) and precompiled binaries are fantastic bonuses.

Comment: @merv, hmm alright. The problem is that not all packages are available from `conda-forga`. Currently I use `conda` to bascially get and `R` installation (`r-base`, `r-renv` + some VSCode required stuff. Then I use `renv` for the packages I need. From a reproducibility perspective this works just fine, since all packages required for the analysis are recorded in `renv.lock` with the project. I am only a bit worried about the linking problems you are referring to.