# fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1': execvp: Permission denied

Tags: r, gcc, conda, fatal-error, hpc

I created a conda environment on a HPC node and want to install a R package called "ape" but got a fatal error message.

when I run `install.packages"ape"`

I got the error message
`x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1': execvp: Permission denied.`

I installed the gcc by `conda install -c conda-forge gxx_linux-64` but it still doesn't work.

I don't have permission to use apt-get install gcc since I am not an admin of the HPC. What can I do to fix this? Any recommendations will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Converted the Comment to an Answer since that helped.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not using `install.packages`, instead install the Conda Forge package `r-ape` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60767530/570918). Also, you get the amazing bonus that everything is precompiled (super fast install, especially if using `mamba`).