# Installing odbc R package in conda env in WSL

Tags: r, ubuntu, anaconda, odbc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to

`install.packages("odbc")`

inside an R 4.2.2 kernel running in anaconda, in WSL (Ubuntu-22.04 distro). The reason I am running anaconda in WSL rather than in Windows is because I need R=4.2.2, and the Windows R base on anaconda is a bit behind at 4.1.3 (see https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-base)

I can `install.packages("odbc")` on a Windows install of anaconda, just not on an anaconda installation on Ubuntu in WSL.

When running
`install.packages("odbc")`

I get this error:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.stat.auckland.ac.nz/src/contrib/odbc_1.3.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 338480 bytes (330 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 330 KB

* installing *source* package ‘odbc’ ...
** package ‘odbc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
PKG_CFLAGS=
PKG_LIBS=-lodbc
<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because odbc was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: unixodbc-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: unixODBC-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: unixodbc_dev (Solaris)
 * pacman: unixodbc (Archlinux, Manjaro, etc)
 * brew: unixodbc (Mac OSX)
To use a custom odbc set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR and PKG_LIBS manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=... PKG_LIBS=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘odbc’
* removing ‘/home/toma/anaconda3/envs/r_422/lib/R/library/odbc’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpzR29mc/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("odbc") :
  installation of package ‘odbc’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have done the suggested sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev, and have these versions:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
unixodbc-dev is already the newest version (2.3.9-5).
unixodbc is already the newest version (2.3.9-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

This didn't work, so I followed these instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server

```
if ! [[ "18.04 20.04 22.04" == *"$(lsb_release -rs)"* ]];
then
    echo "Ubuntu $(lsb_release -rs) is not currently supported.";
    exit;
fi

sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```

I still get the earlier error about missing sql.h, however this file does exist in

```
~anaconda3/pkgs/unixodbc-2.3.11-h5eee18b_0/include/sql.h
~anaconda3/include/sql.h
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If using Conda R, then it is usually better to avoid `install.packages` for anything other than pure R packages. The CRAN `odbc` package goes by `r-odbc` on Conda Forge. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60767530/570918. Conda will bring all the dependencies with it, and everything is precompiled (only needs copying).

Answer (score 0):

as the conf error states: `Configuration failed because odbc was not found (!)` . So you have the needed dependencies installed (twice); but your R session can't access them, because the PATH vars are not provided. This could be due to the way your conda envs are set up. It seems you want to use `r_422` at `‘/home/toma/anaconda3/envs/r_422'`

Point R to the unixODBC installation by providing the path during or prior of  the install.

As the message suggests, you could call R from bash in following fashion :

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=... PKG_LIBS=...
```

...or from inside of R:

```
install.packages("odbc", configure.vars=c("LIB_DIR='r_422/lib/R/library/' INCLUDE_DIR='anaconda3/pkgs/unixodbc-2.3.11-h5eee18b_0/include/sql.h''"))
```

... or add the path to .Renviron file, and restart R

```
echo "INCLUDE_DIR='anaconda3/pkgs/unixodbc-2.3.11-h5eee18b_0/include/sql.h'" > .Renviron
```

... with the right paths to unixODBC (either the one that you manually installed into `conda pkgs` or the system wide version you installed through `apt`)
To find the location of the apt version of odbc you could use dpkg list:

```
dpkg -L unixodbc
```

This will give you a list of the source files of unixodbc.

Comment: Thanks. The installation gets further now, but some secondary process now can't access the PATH:

/home/toma/anaconda3/envs/r_422/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lodbc: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/toma/anaconda3/envs/r_422/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: odbc.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘odbc’
* removing ‘/home/toma/anaconda3/envs/r_422/lib/R/library/odbc’

Comment: how experienced are you with conda envs? maybe it is easier if you would just use apt and handle envs with multiple WSL instances instead?

Comment: I'm pretty good with conda - but completely new to R. That is why I'm using conda - so I can switch from my comfort zone of python to this strange R beast. Ideally I can write my python code and R code both in jupyter-lab, and just switch kernels