# cannot install tidyverse in jupyter. warning message: installation of tidyverse had non-zero exit

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, tidyverse, conda, install.packages

**I have been trying to install tidyverse in R (Jupyter). getting the following message:**

```
> *Warning message:
> "dependency 'MASS' is not available"also installing the dependencies 'htmltools', 'processx', 'xfun', 'bslib', 'tinytex', 'lifecycle', 'glue', 'tidyselect', 'vctrs', 'gtable', 'scales', 'gargle', 'timechange', 'systemfonts', 'vroom', 'progress', 'callr', 'knitr', 'rmarkdown', 'broom', 'conflicted', 'cli', 'dbplyr', 'dplyr', 'dtplyr', 'forcats', 'ggplot2', 'googledrive', 'googlesheets4', 'haven', 'hms', 'jsonlite', 'lubridate', 'magrittr', 'modelr', 'pillar', 'purrr', 'ragg', 'readr', 'readxl', 'reprex', 'rlang', 'rvest', 'stringr', 'tibble', 'tidyr', 'xml2'
> 
> 
> There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
> binary source needs_compilation
> htmltools     0.5.1.1  0.5.7              TRUE
> processx        3.5.2  3.8.3              TRUE
> xfun             0.22   0.41              TRUE
> bslib           0.2.4  0.6.1             FALSE
> tinytex          0.31   0.49             FALSE
> lifecycle       1.0.0  1.0.4             FALSE
> glue            1.4.2  1.7.0              TRUE
> tidyselect      1.1.1  1.2.0             FALSE
> vctrs           0.3.8  0.6.5              TRUE
> gtable          0.3.0  0.3.4             FALSE
> scales          1.1.1  1.3.0              TRUE
> gargle          1.1.0  1.5.2             FALSE
> timechange      0.0.2  0.2.0              TRUE
> systemfonts     1.0.2  1.0.5              TRUE
> vroom           1.4.0  1.6.5              TRUE
> progress        1.2.2  1.2.3             FALSE
> callr           3.7.0  3.7.3             FALSE
> knitr            1.33   1.45             FALSE
> rmarkdown         2.8   2.25             FALSE
> broom           0.7.6  1.0.5             FALSE
> conflicted      1.0.4  1.2.0             FALSE
> cli             2.5.0  3.6.2              TRUE
> dbplyr          2.1.1  2.4.0             FALSE
> dplyr           1.0.6  1.1.4              TRUE
> dtplyr          1.1.0  1.3.1             FALSE
> forcats         0.5.1  1.0.0             FALSE
> ggplot2         3.3.3  3.4.4             FALSE
> googledrive     1.0.1  2.1.1             FALSE
> googlesheets4   0.3.0  1.1.1             FALSE
> haven           2.4.1  2.5.4              TRUE
> hms             1.0.0  1.1.3             FALSE
> jsonlite        1.7.2  1.8.8              TRUE
> lubridate      1.7.10  1.9.3              TRUE
> magrittr        2.0.1  2.0.3              TRUE
> modelr          0.1.8 0.1.11             FALSE
> pillar          1.6.0  1.9.0             FALSE
> purrr           0.3.4  1.0.2              TRUE
> ragg            1.1.2  1.2.7              TRUE
> readr           1.4.0  2.1.5              TRUE
> readxl          1.3.1  1.4.3              TRUE
> reprex          2.0.0  2.1.0             FALSE
> rlang          0.4.11  1.1.3              TRUE
> rvest           1.0.0  1.0.3             FALSE
> stringr         1.4.0  1.5.1             FALSE
> tibble          3.1.1  3.2.1              TRUE
> tidyr           1.1.3  1.3.0              TRUE
> xml2            1.3.2  1.3.6              TRUE
> tidyverse       1.3.1  2.0.0             FALSE
> 
> Binaries will be installed
> package 'htmltools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> Warning message:
> "cannot remove prior installation of package 'htmltools'"Warning message in file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE):
> "problem copying C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\R\library\00LOCK\htmltools\libs\x64\htmltools.dll to C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\R\library\htmltools\libs\x64\htmltools.dll: Permission denied"Warning message:
> "restored 'htmltools'"
> package 'processx' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'glue' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'vctrs' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'scales' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'timechange' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'systemfonts' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'vroom' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'cli' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'dplyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'haven' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'jsonlite' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> Warning message:
> "cannot remove prior installation of package 'jsonlite'"Warning message in file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE):
> "problem copying C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\R\library\00LOCK\jsonlite\libs\x64\jsonlite.dll to C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\R\library\jsonlite\libs\x64\jsonlite.dll: Permission denied"Warning message:
> "restored 'jsonlite'"
> package 'lubridate' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'magrittr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'purrr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'ragg' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'readr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'readxl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'rlang' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> Warning message:
> "cannot remove prior installation of package 'rlang'"Warning message in file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE):
> "problem copying C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\R\library\00LOCK\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\R\library\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied"Warning message:
> "restored 'rlang'"
> package 'tibble' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'tidyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package 'xml2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> 
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>   C:\Users\rhasa\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpG2RZe9\downloaded_packages
> installing the source packages 'bslib', 'tinytex', 'lifecycle', 'tidyselect', 'gtable', 'gargle', 'progress', 'callr', 'knitr', 'rmarkdown', 'broom', 'conflicted', 'dbplyr', 'dtplyr', 'forcats', 'ggplot2', 'googledrive', 'googlesheets4', 'hms', 'modelr', 'pillar', 'reprex', 'rvest', 'stringr', 'tidyverse'
> 
> Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'tinytex' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'lifecycle' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'callr' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'knitr' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'conflicted' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'bslib' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'tidyselect' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'gtable' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'gargle' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'forcats' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'hms' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'pillar' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'rvest' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'stringr' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'progress' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'rmarkdown' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'broom' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'dbplyr' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'dtplyr' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'ggplot2' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'googledrive' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'googlesheets4' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'modelr' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'reprex' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("tidyverse"):
> "installation of package 'tidyverse' had non-zero exit status"*
```

uninstalled r and r studio deleted all anaconda folders. uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda

Comment: Try installing `MASS` on its own and then try again. You may also need to heed the warnings about removing prior installations of othe4 packages.

Comment: When working with conda environments, your packages should be installed through conda and you'd generally want to avoid `install.packages()`. Tidyverse 2.0 is available through conda-forge, https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-tidyverse

Comment: Probably relevant, RE: don't use `install.packages` in Conda environments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60767530/570918