# How to use R that is installed in conda environment from the standalone (non-Anaconda) installation of RStudio?

Tags: r, anaconda, conda

Is there a way to use R that is installed in conda environment from the standalone (non-Anaconda) installation of RStudio? The reason for it is that Anaconda version of RStudion is very outdated.

**Warning!**  If you select path to conda R version here `Tools...Global Options...General...R Version`, nothing is displayed in RStudio window and you will need to reinstall RStudio and reset all settings.

Comment: In RStudio, go to "Tools...Global Options...General...R Version" You can choose which ever R executable you want to use. Just point to the one that's in your conda environment.

Comment: @MrFlick I did that now and RStudio did not displays anything. I reinstalled RStudio and reseted all settings to fix this.

Comment: You probably didn't need to reinstall, rather just need to reset one of the configuration files `.Renviron` or `.Rprofile`. Not sure what platform you are on. In Mac OS X, it is sufficient to activate the env and then launch RStudio from the shell (`/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/RStudio`). This let's one dynamically choose which R environment to run without having to set a config.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up conda-installed R for use with RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534383/how-to-set-up-conda-installed-r-for-use-with-rstudio)