# Update R in anaconda

Tags: r, ubuntu, anaconda, rstudio, conda

My first idea was to get R version 4 on my rstudio beside anaconda

My ADD brain then fought getting the newest version of R in my base environment

I have before created new conda environments with different versions of R without a problem

Now I start R in my Ubuntu 18.04.5 and get:

R version 3.5.1

I download the newest version of R (should be 4.0.5) with `conda install -c conda-forge r-base`

I restart the computer but I am stuck in R version 3.5.1

I do `conda update -n base conda` and nothing changes

```
conda config --show-sources
```

> ```
> ==> /home/notandi/anaconda3/.condarc <==
> channels:
>   - conda-forge
>   - bioconda
>   - defaults
>
> ==> /home/notandi/.condarc <==
> channels:
>   - bioconda
>   - defaults
> ```

conda info:

> ```
>  active environment : base
> active env location : /home/notandi/anaconda3
>         shell level : 1
>    user config file : /home/notandi/.condarc  populated config files : /home/notandi/anaconda3/.condarc
>                       /home/notandi/.condarc
>       conda version : 4.10.1
> conda-build version : 3.20.2
>      python version : 3.7.7.final.0
>    virtual packages : __linux=4.15.0=0
>                       __glibc=2.27=0
>                       __unix=0=0
>                       __archspec=1=x86_64
>    base environment : /home/notandi/anaconda3  (writable)
>   conda av data dir : /home/notandi/anaconda3/etc/conda   conda av metadata url : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
>        channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64
>                       https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>                       https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
>                       https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
>       package cache : /home/notandi/anaconda3/pkgs
>                       /home/notandi/.conda/pkgs
>    envs directories : /home/notandi/anaconda3/envs
>                       /home/notandi/.conda/envs
>            platform : linux-64
>          user-agent : conda/4.10.1 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.7.7 Linux/4.15.0-143-generic ubuntu/18.04.5 glibc/2.27
>             UID:GID : 1000:1000
>          netrc file : None
>        offline mode : False
> ```

What does the Singularity want from me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up conda-installed R for use with RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534383/how-to-set-up-conda-installed-r-for-use-with-rstudio) Personally, I use [this workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737170/570918) [disclaimer: also my answer].

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me is to update the place where Anaconda is looking for the packages. To do that:

1. Open Anaconda
2. Go to Environments and select your desired environment
3. Lets add a new channel to look for updated packages: button Channels --> click Add --> type **conda-forge** --> enter --> click Update Channels
4. Lets wait until Anaconda update packages list and look for the R package (now it should show you the last version) and either update it or installed it from crash.