# Anaconda navigator does not start because of missing plugin cocoa - macOS 11.1

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

When I do `anaconda-navigator` in the terminal, anaconda navigator does not start and prompt :

```
(base) vincentclerc@MacBook-Pro-de-Vincent ~ % anaconda-navigator
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa"
in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
zsh: abort      anaconda-navigator
```

This started to happen after installing Rstudio.
I tried

```
conda remove anaconda-navigator
conda install anaconda-navigator
```

and

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
anaconda-navigator --reset
```

I also tried :

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.34
```

because of Qt, but without result.

Comment: Installing RStudio through Conda is a very bad idea. It is an abandoned project, and so ends up forcing the environment to use old versions of some core libraries (e.g., `icu`), and can lead to compatibility issues. Using a native install (one instance) of RStudio is a much better option. See [some tips on using Conda environments in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737170/570918).