# How to change R lib path within conda environment permanently

Tags: r, conda

I have created a conda environment in which I installed a progream from github which also utilizes R packages. However when I test the install of the program it cannot find the neccasary R packages.

When I go to R and check the library path, I can see it is not looking for the packages within the environment first.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/kusers/ancillary/mradzieta/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0"
[2] "/data/mradzieta/anaconda3/envs/squeezemeta/lib/R/library"
```

Within R, I did reorder the libpaths doing this:

```
> myPaths <- .libPaths()
> myPaths <- c(myPaths[2], myPaths[1])
> .libPaths(myPaths)
> .libPaths()
[1] "/data/mradzieta/anaconda3/envs/squeezemeta/lib/R/library"  
[2] "/kusers/ancillary/mradzieta/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0"
```

However when I exit R and test the install again, R reverts back to the original libpath order as it is only changed within that R session.

How do I reorder the libpaths permanently within my conda environment so they don't revert back to the original order?

Comment: Have you tried setting an environment variable like `R_LIBS`? How R initializes the library search path at startup is documented in `?.libPaths`.

Comment: @MikaelJagan I tried that but it made no difference

Comment: Can you share what you tried? Another option is to set the library search path in an init file, like `.Rprofile`. See `?Startup`.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this issue. The issue was an .Renviron file in the home directory which directed R_LIBS= to the wrong R library. Changing this to the conda installed library fixed my issue.

Comment: Better, just delete or comment out the `R_LIBS` entry and let the shell environment variables define it. That way, whatever environment is active when launching `rstudio` will automatically point to the correct location.

Comment: @merv Hi, may I further ask the detailed steps to do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Bio_farmer this is what I do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737170/570918. That is, assuming you've cleaned up the `.Renviron` file to remove any `R_LIBS` entry.