# RStudio's R system() does not see conda, but the terminal on the same macbook does (and terminal R too)

Tags: python, r, rstudio, conda, environment

Why does this happen?

Inside RStudio's `R` console:

```
> system("conda --info")
sh: conda: command not found
Warning message:
In system("conda --info") : error in running command
```

But the MacBook terminal sees it:

```
(base) 192:~ avoda$ conda --version
conda 4.10.3
```

So I tried checking whether the `R` available in terminal saw conda and it does:

```
(base) 192:~ avoda$ R

R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) -- "Camp Pontanezen"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

> system("conda --version")
conda 4.10.3
>
```

So the terminal and terminal-R see `conda`, but RStudio's `R` does not. Why does that happen?

PS:
Terminal-`R` and RStudio-console-`R` seem to be the same `R`-software version (4.1.0), but have different environments?

Comment: Seems similar to this: https://community.rstudio.com/t/conda-command-not-found-in-rstudio-terminal/64565

Comment: Compare `Sys.getenv("PATH")` (in R) with `echo "${PATH}"` (on the terminal). In the short-term, you can modify the `PATH` that R is seeing *in this process* by using `Sys.setenv(PATH=...)`, extending the existing PATH with where you know conda to be installed, using the appropriate os-specific separator. In the medium-term, you can add it via `~/.Renviron` or `~/.Rprofile`, but really this is a `PATH` issue that needs to be fixed at the shell or OS levels.

Comment: See [this](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#I-get-_0060_0060command-not-found_0027_0027-in-the-GUI-yet-it-works-in-the-Terminal-_002d_002d-why_003f) section of the R for macOS FAQ. When started from a shell, R inherits `PATH` from that shell. That is not the case when R is started via a GUI like RStudio.

Comment: @r2evans It's not a shell or OS issue, _per se_. It's really a GUI issue, and setting `PATH` in `~/.Renviron` or `~/.Rprofile` _is_ the recommended solution.

Comment: I understand that it fixes this issue, but ... if R and RStudio are not seeing the correct `PATH`, then it is arguable that something is misconfigured in the user's environment. In my use-case (and therefore my assumption), R is not the only mechanism through which I access python, so fixing it in R alone is just half the battle. I recognize I may be in the minority here, but that's why I suggested that it may be better to set that at a grander level. YMMV, thanks.

Comment: I see your point about RStudio *not* inheriting `PATH` ... that seems like a completely broken thing, not sure why that's preferred ... but since I don't use RStudio (I use emacs/ess), I don't have much game in that fight.

Comment: @r2evans That makes sense - thanks for clarifying. In that case, the OP can modify the global default `PATH` by placing a text file containing the path to `conda` in the system directory `/etc/paths.d/` (example [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-do-i-set-the-global-path-environment-variable-on-os-x)). That would affect _all_ applications, started with or without a shell, including RStudio.

Comment: This is what I do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737170/570918

Answer (score -1):

Conda gets added to the user's interactive shell *dynamically*, but RStudio's default configuration is an non-login shell (e.g., `/bin/bash` or `/bin/zsh`).

Go to the RStudio settings **Tools > Terminal > Terminal options...**, change it to use a custom shell `/bin/bash` or `/bin/zsh`, and then add to **Custom shell command-line options:** a `-l` or `-i`, respectively. Something like:

[image]

This will launch into **base** (assuming auto-activate is on), but `conda` will at least be available.