# Connect my system's Rstudio to anaconda environment with R. Windows

Tags: r, windows, anaconda

I am working on Windows 10. I have installed RStudio directly on my machine. On the other hand I have installed Anaconda with R. Is it possible to connect my system's RStudio with the R running in one environment in Anaconda?

Comment: In RStudio, you can go to the Tools...Global Options...General...Basic. And the first input on that tab allows you to choose which R version to run. You should be able to point that to the version of R that you installed with Anaconda.

Comment: Hi MrFlick, thanks for your reply. It was my first try. I pointed to the R folder inside my conda environment folder. However, Rstudio warned I had to restart the program. I did it, and after restarting RStudio, it got damaged and it did not open. Thus, I should to reinstall my system's Rstudio. Any other option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up conda-installed R for use with RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534383/how-to-set-up-conda-installed-r-for-use-with-rstudio)

Comment: Hi @merv, I have been trying the options in that post but it did not work for me. They are explained for linux and mac, and I am on Windows. I am trying to figure out how that solution should work  on Win but I dont get it yet.

Comment: What happens when you activate an environment (in `cmd.exe` or Anaconda Prompt) and then type `RStudio`?