# Why does using conda to install rstudio, r version 4, using conda on my linux system return an error about incompatable specifications?

Tags: r, rstudio, conda

I'm trying to use condas to install r and rstudio

```
conda create -c conda-forge -n r4rs r-base=4.0.* rstudio

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving
> environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will
> retry with next repodata source. Collecting package metadata
> (repodata.json): done Solving environment: /  Found conflicts! Looking
> for incompatible packages. This can take several minutes.  Press
> CTRL-C to abort. failed                                               
> 
> 
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be
> incompatible with each other:
> 
> Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
> 
> Package r-base conflicts for: rstudio ->
> r-base64enc[version='>=0.1-3'] ->
> r-base[version='3.1.3.*|3.2.0.*|3.2.1.*|3.2.2.*|3.3.2.*|3.4.1.*|>=3.4.1,<3.4.2.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=4.0,<4.1.0a0|>=4.1,<4.2.0a0|>=3.5.1,<3.5.2.0a0|>=3.5.0,<3.5.1.0a0|>=3.4.3,<3.4.4.0a0|>=3.4.2,<3.4.3a0|3.3.1.*|3.4.1|>=3.4.2|>=3.3.2|>=3.3.1|3.2.2'] r-base=4.0The following specifications were found to be incompatible
> with your system:
> 
>   - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.27=0
>   - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.27=0
>   - rstudio -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
> 
> Your installed version is: 2.27
```

However,

```
 conda create -c r -n r4rs r-base rstudio
```

seems to install `r` and `rstudio` just fine.

I'm at a loss about what this means or how I'd even begin to solve this issue. Maybe I just need to submit a bug report and accept that this isn't going to happen for now, but if there is some way I can move forward, I'd love to hear it.

```
uname -rv


> 5.4.0-99-generic #112~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 3 14:09:57 UTC 2022
```

Comment: A crucial difference between the two commands is that they're pulling from different channels - the first uses `conda-forge` and the second uses `r`.

Comment: Yeah, don't use the Conda `rstudio` - it's not maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue with dependencies, as `rstudio` does not seem to be solvable with `r-base=4.0.*` specified.

This works:
conda create -c conda-forge -n r4rs r-base rstudio
This does not:
conda create -c conda-forge -n r4rs r-base=4.0.* rstudio

Probable reason might be that the `rstudio` package in the conda channel is not very actively maintained and hasn't seen an update in over a year, see [here](https://anaconda.org/r/rstudio)

Depending on what can give here, you could:

1. Accept the option of `conda create -c conda-forge -n r4rs r-base rstudio` which will give you `r-base<4.0`
2. Download and install your own version of `rstudio` from the [official website](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) and create an environment with just `r-base==4.0.*`, activate that env and then start your downloaded rstudio, which should detect the `r` you have installed into the conda env. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534383/how-to-set-up-conda-installed-r-for-use-with-rstudio)