# Can't install recent version of Rstudio in Ubuntu 22.04 through anaconda

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio, conda

When tried to install through terminal command:

> conda install -c r rstudio

The terminal got stuck in solving environmental step forever. I manually killed the process.

Then I tried to install Rstudio from anaconda-navigator by creating a new environment for R and python 3.7. The only available (listed) Rstudio version were from 1.0.44 and 1.1.456. I can install version 1.0.44 but not 1.1.456. Greater issue for me that the  latest versions are not even listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `r` channel - Anaconda has not kept up maintenance on it. Instead, use Conda Forge. Also, I would strongly discourage installing anything R in an Anaconda **base** environment or any other environment that has Python installed. Instead, create a new one:

```bash
conda create -n rstudio -c conda-forge rstudio-desktop r-base=4.1
```

Specifying the `r-base`, which controls the version, is optional but recommended. This should work for either 4.0 or 4.1.

---

### Additional Commentary

I'm a strong advocate of keeping infrastructure and execution environments separated. This allows one to keep updating them independent. Unlike Jupyter, RStudio still doesn't have clean way to load Conda R environments. For that reason, I still recommend using a native RStudio installation, as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737170/570918).