# How to create R environment with conda-forge channel only

Tags: r, anaconda, conda, reproducible-research, renv

I am trying to create an environment without using the Defaults channel that has R, RStudio, and renv.

According to [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/is-conda-free): "As of 2020, certain organizations have to pay to access default or use Anaconda Distribution, while others could continue to use it for free." I fall within the category of working for an organization that would need a paid license to use the defaults channel. Hence, I am trying to create an r environment with conda in a way that is completely free.

The back story is that I am trying to create a new environment per this [suggestion](https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/80#issuecomment-1726608938) for reproducibility. Since renv does not enforce the version of R specified in a lockfile, I am trying to create an r environment in conda, save that to a yaml file, and have another user use it to re-create the environment. renv will then be used to enforce the same versions of r packages and dependencies.

When I run `conda create -n QAQC -c conda-forge r-base rstudio`, and see the new packages to be installed, I see that some dependencies (like r-markdown) are listed as coming from the pkgs/r or pkgs/main channels. The first channel looks like the [R Language Channel](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/working-with-conda/reference/r-language-pkg-docs/), which is mentioned as: Anaconda, Inc.’s R conda packages and Microsoft R Open conda packages. This channel is included in conda’s “defaults” channel.

So if the R channel is in the defaults channel, and the defaults channel is not free, is there any way possible to create an r environment that is not violating the Terms of Service?

Comment: Marked duplicate should cover this (please say if it doesn't). TLDR: If you don't want to edit global config, then either add `--override-channels` flag to commands or add `nodefaults` as a "channel" to YAML definitions. For fresh Conda **base** installs, prefer Miniforge installer (uses only Conda Forge as default), or Micromamba (baseless, with no default channels).

Comment: Also, is the `rstudio` from Conda really needed? I strongly recommend against installing an IDE in an environment that is for compute kernel. Further, there are no regularly maintained versions of RStudio on Conda - I would stick to a native RStudio install and use Conda only to manage R environments.

Comment: @merv, thank you! `conda create --name QAQC -c conda-forge --override-channels r-base=4.1.3 r-renv=0.17.3` worked. Regarding rstudio install, could you help offer a suggestion on how to open RStudio so that it points to the specific r environment created here for reproducibility? In other words, the only way I can think of is `activate QACQ` and then `rstudio` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534383/how-to-set-up-conda-installed-r-for-use-with-rstudio#:~:text=conda%20has%20the%20package%20rstudioapi,inside%20your%20environment)%3A%20rstudio

Comment: I should mention, I tried your answer to that question, but does not seem to work for me in Windows. In cmd, `conda: command not found`.

Comment: I don't use Windows, but it appears to have [a GUI for selecting the version](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-the-RStudio-Desktop-IDE) (hold Ctrl when launching). Does that work? Unsure if that has issues with loading the correct dynamic libraries.

Comment: @merv Thanks, unfortunately, that didn't work for me. On one computer I get the same error as here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-rstudio-within-a-conda-environment/128780. On another computer I get the following error when trying to connect to the R install within the conda env: The code execution cannot proceed because libbz2-1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem. (Actually about 5 similar error windows open, each with a different .dll file specified.)